# applying scopes on angular directives and calling object function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code works fine and uses the parent controller scope;

```
"<button type='button'  post-random-feed >Post review</button>"

.directive("postRandomFeed",['config',function(){
        return function(scope,element.attrs){ 

                element.bind("click", function(){
                    scope.name ="henry";
                     console.log(element);
                });



    }
}]);
```

my problem is that i want to define an isolated scope and return an object instead of a function from the directive. This is my code

```
"<button type='button'  post-random-feed >Post review</button>"

.directive("postRandomFeed",['config',function(){
        return { 

            restrict :"A",

            scope : {

                    },

            irony : function(element, attrs)
            {   
                element.bind("click", function(){
                     console.log(element);
                });


            }
    };
}]);
```

How do i call the irony function so that the element registers the click event any mistakes please correct me. Thank you

Comment: You can put that in link function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a callback to the controller:

html:

```
<button type='button'  post-random-feed on-irony="onControllerFn">Post review</button>
```

directive:

```
.directive("postRandomFeed",['config',function(){
        return { 
            restrict :"A",
            scope : {},
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {   
                $timeout(function () {
                   scope.$emit(attr.onIrony);
                });
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

and in controller you can do:

```
$scope.$on('onControllerFn', function(event) {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: how does this get an object passed to controller scope?

Comment: inside the scope we can specify it whether we want one way binding or two way binding if needed... i thought the question was to getting a function into the controller

Comment: Thank you. it was exactly what i needed

Comment: @TariiqHenryBbosa Believe me, this is **not** what you need. This is one big antipattern. You need to use `&` binding function. But whatever.

Comment: The question was "How do i call the irony function". Your example doesn't even have it.

Comment: Well i figured it out i just needed to use the link attribute